# Check if script was started by another script

Tags: linux, bash

I have two scripts: script1.sh and script2.sh.
script1.sh is executing script2.sh. This is how it looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
./script2.sh
```

How to show in script2.sh by which script was executed? For example

```
./script1.sh
```

and then I have an output

```
script2.sh was executed by script1.sh
```

Comment: [What problem are you trying to solve?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) You can pass calling script name as the first argument like this: `./script2.sh ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}`

Comment: Hi yeputons, Yes I could, but I have many "parents" scripts which  invoke  one child script and I don't want to change their content.

Comment: assuming script 1 does not exit before script 2 completes, you could have script 2 get its parent process id (ppid) with something like  " myppid=`ps -p ${pid:-$$} -o ppid=`   "  then have the script use that to get the caller name.